# Persist data in Repository for multiple Views using MVP

Tags: android, mvp

I've a `View1` <--> `Presenter1` <--> `Repository`.
In some moment of time I create `View2` <--> `Presenter2`. All the necessary data has already been loaded when `View1` was created. All I need is to use it in `Presenter2`. How can I do this? I'm more interested in Repository pattern approach. 
Should I do it like this?:

```
class Repository {
    private val list;

    getData() {
        ...
        list = result;
    }
}
```

If so, how can I keep `list` persistant and not lose it's info through out `View1` and `View2` lifetime?

I usually pass `Repository` like this `Presenter(new Repository)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best approach in this case would be to use dependency injection (dagger2) to inject the same instance of your repository class in each presenter. To do so you could make your repository class a singleton:

**Appmodule.java**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    ...

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DataRepository provideDataRepository() {
        return new DataRepository();
    }
}
```

By using the Singleton scope your repository object is unique throughout your app. If you don't know how to use dagger you could create a singleton class yourself, but I strongly suggest you to lookup how to use dagger because that will make your app more decoupled and easily testable.

Then in your presenter all you'd have to do is to inject the instance of the repository.

**MyPresenter.java**

```
class MyPresenter{

   private DataRepository repo;

   @Inject
   private MyPresenter(DataRepository repository){
     this.repo = repository;
   }
}
```